# Почему меняется тип объекта? (виртуальная функция)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, объекты, виртуальная-функция

Есть родительский класс command и два дочерних - movement и root.
Заголовочный файл:

```
class Command {
public:
    static const int TIME_MIN = 0;
    static const int TIME_DEFAULT = 0;
    int getTime() const;
    void setTime(const int time);
    virtual void setValue(const int value);
    virtual int getValue() const;
protected:
    int time_current;
};

class Movement : public Command {
public:
    static const int SPEED_MAX = 100;
    static const int SPEED_DEFAULT = 0;
    static const int SPEED_MIN = 0;
    Movement();
    Movement(const int time, const int speed);
    Movement(const Movement &car);
    virtual void setValue(const int value) override;
    virtual int getValue() const override;
private:
    int speed_current;
};

class Root : public Command {
public:
    static const int RADIUS_MAX = 100;
    static const int RADIUS_MIN = -100;
    static const int RADIUS_DEFAUT = 0;
    Root(const int time, const int radius);
    Root();
    virtual void setValue(const int value) override;
    virtual int getValue() const override;
private:
    //+ means right, - means left; by default right with radius +
    int radius_current;
};
```

Реализация виртуальных функций:

```
int Command::getValue() const {
    return 99;
}

void Command::setValue(const int value) {
};

int Movement::getValue() const {
    return speed_current;
}

int Root::getValue() const {
    return radius_current;
}

void Movement::setValue(const int value) {
    if (value >= SPEED_MAX)
        speed_current = SPEED_MAX;
    else if (value <= SPEED_MIN)
        speed_current = SPEED_MIN;
    else
        speed_current = value;
}

void Root::setValue(const int value) {
    if (value >= RADIUS_MAX)
        radius_current = RADIUS_MAX;
    else if (value <= RADIUS_MIN)
        radius_current = RADIUS_MIN;
    else
        radius_current = value;
}
```

Объекты класса Command хранятся в очереди:

```
class CarCollection {
private:
    struct ListElement {
        Command data;
        ListElement *next;
    };
public:
    void add(const Command &obj); // метод добавления
    ListElement *first;
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Само добавление в очередь:

```
void CarCollection::add(const Command &d) {
    // добавление элемента в очередь
    ListElement* cur = first;
    while(cur->next) cur = cur->next;
    cur->data = d; //тип movement -> тип command
    cur->next = new ListElement();
    this->size++;
}
```

Проблема в том, что, если я создаю объект дочернего класса и хочу добавить его в коллекцию, то на строчке

```
cur->data = d; //тип movement -> тип command
```

меняется тип объекта на родительский и я теряю информацию из дочернего класса.
Сам вызов:

```
CarCollection queue;
Movement car(58,50);
queue.add(car)
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Большое спасибо

Comment: Тип `data` объявлен как `Command`, тип `d` объявлен как `const Command &`. Тип какого объекта тут меняется по-вашему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это эффект [*срезки*](https://it.wikireading.ru/27528) - вы объявили, что в структуре хранится родительский объект, вот при *копировании* потомок и урезается до родителя. Просто подумайте - *куда*, например, копировать лишние поля потомка (по сравнению с предком), если размер места в структуре это просто не позволяет?

Храните указатели на объекты - и все будет хорошо. Указатели - они все одного размера :) Сказал бы - храните ссылки, но это просто так, без прокси-класса, не сработает, так что проще хранить указатели.

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось. Но теперь возник вопрос как имея ссылку на объект класса вызвать его методы.  Я пытался `ptr->data->getValue()` и `*(ptr->data).getValue()`, но это только вызывает ошибки. ptr - указатель на элемент очереди

Comment: Вы бы не могли привести текст самой ошибки, и несколько строк - объявления ptr и т.п. - по вашему описанию трудно понять, что у вас не так.